# Clear out existing angular ui router query params when switching to the same route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular ui router to route bewteen my pages and I have a route that has a few different query parameters. The problem is that when I switch routes for that same page with different query parameters, any existing parameters stay in place.

So if I'm at url `localhost:8080/myapp/#/myPath?barId=098` and I use one of the below items I end up at url `localhost:8080/myapp/#/myPath?barId=098&fooId=123` instead of `localhost:8080/myapp/#/myPath?fooId=123`

I've tried using `ui-sref="myPath({fooId:123}"` and `$state.go("myPath", {fooId:123})` but they both result in the same behavior. Is there a way to remove existing parameters?

Here's the state definition

```
.state('myPath', {
   url: '/myPath?fooId&barId&fluffyId&anotherId',
   templateUrl: 'foo.html',
   controller: MyController
})
```

Comment: What is "myPath"? What happens if you add reload like this: $state.go("foo", {fooId:123}, { reload: true});

Comment: Made a mistake when changing the names. myPath should have been the path, just mistakenly put foo in there. The `reload:true` didn't make a difference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ui-router sref options defaults inherit to true. I think you need to set it to false like this:

```
$state.go("myPath", {fooId:123}, {inherit: false})
```

Or in the view like this:

```
ui-sref="myPath({fooId:123}" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, inherit: false}"
```

You can read about the ui-sref-opts in the [documentation for ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go) here.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that, was typing faster than I was thinking.